# How to keep yellow folders expanded in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

Every time I nav back to the file tree browser in Xcode 4, whether from debugging, examining the build log, etc., it closes my main "yellow" folder which contains my project sources. Thus I have to dig through multiple levels of folders to get back to the files I was just editing, e.g. before the build.  It also keeps auto-expanding the 'blue' folders which are references to trees that I *don't* need to browse and would prefer to keep closed.

Apple is ignoring its own UI guidelines which say that STABILITY is the primary feature of a good UI. Xcode 4 is so buggy and the UX is so cumbersome it's nearly a laugh.

How can I get Xcode 4.2.1 on OS X 10.7.3 to keep my open folders open, and closed folders closed, in the file tree browser?!

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what exactly do you do that triggers the folders to close. I can quit Xcode 4 altogether and they will be open again when I come back.

Comment: Sounds like your config works the way it should. I migrated a SL machine to Lion, then installed XCode 4.2.1 from the app store. Pretty much any action that changes the navigator view from project (file hierarchy) to anything else, e.g. search, debug, etc. results in the source folders all being collapsed when returning to the project pane. (Without quitting XCode, just as a normal workflow.) Might there be some magic prefs/plist file somewhere to reset !? Or some reason it can't remember its view state from moment to moment?

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but I've been having this problem in Xcode 8. It's extremely annoying and time consuming always drilling down the hierarchy again... Did you ever resolve this?